# gdb displays gibberish with CJK

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm sure this is caused by the encoding of `gdb` and found the command to alter encoding in gdb:

`set charset charsetname`

I tried `utf8`, `UTF8`, `UTF-8`, `utf-8`,`gbk`, `gb2312` and so on to replace the `charsetname`, but all returned: `Undefined name: charsetname`.

How do I know what encodings does `gdb` support ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input

```
set charset
```

Then press TAB key twice, GDB will list the names of the character sets that can be used.

Comment: I found it only supports `ASCII` and `ISO-8859-1`, neither supports CJK. Anyway to add new charset ?

Comment: @CDT That's beyond my knowledge. Why not ask a new question if google isn't helpful